# Can we add bounty to anyone's question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I came across [this bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378098) and noticed that the question is asked by [husky love](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5652558/husky-love) but the bounty is given by [vitordcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1822403/vitorsdcs).

How this is possible? Can you add a bounty to another user's question?

Comment: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @Vin thanks . link is very helpful.

Comment: "the question is asked by husky love" eew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you may offer a bounty for another user's question.

> While you do not need to be the owner of a question to start a bounty
>   on that question, only one bounty can be active on a question at once,
>   and each user can only have up to three active bounties at once.
>   [Read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/325200)

In your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378098/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-android-rating-bars-stroke-not-the-color-of-the-st), you can see that the OP doesn't have enough Rep to put up a bounty. So someone has done it for him.

Refer : [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8352/how-can-i-award-a-bounty-to-another-users-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you have the same question, but there's no answers for it. It's mostly because some users don't have the reputation, to add a bounty on a question.

Some sites even allow you, to put a bounty on answers, for example the code-golf SE.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second paragraph?

Comment: @AakashM Some people put bounties on abswers, to motivate people to help in golfing even further

Comment: Yes, and the way that's done is to put a bounty on the *question* then award it to the *answer* - there's nothing unique to [codegolf.se] here.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. "*You can, if you have the same question..*"- No. You just can period. For whatever reason you seem fit (as long as it is valid- no bounty trading). "*It's mostly because some users don't have the reputation, to add a bounty on a question.*" Hmm what? What are you talking about? Regarding your last point. Wut?